A kids show with a teleporting bicycle
I watched this live action tv show when i was a kid an I can't remember what it was called. It was about a boy who had a special bike that let him go places. There was a bad guy who would ride a motorcycle. It may or may not have had a sidecar attached. The kid would know when and where to go because he had a watch or a ring that had a screen and a man would appear and tell him. I have a strong feeling that this guy was dressed as a wizard but I can't remember for certain. 

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

What you are describing sounds like Storylords.  This was a live-action show broadcast on PBS in 1984.  It was actually an educational show:

Storylords consists of twelve 15-minute programs which focus on
  building reading comprehension strategies through the use of fantasy.
  The storyline consists of a young boy named Norbert who has been
  apprenticed by Lexor – an old Storylord from the land of Mojuste – to
  defend Mojuste's citizens against the wicked Storylord, Thorzuul.
  Thorzuul seeks to turn all of those who can't understand what they
  read into stone statues for his collection.
The first few episodes follow a basic formula: first, Norbert is
summoned by Lexor through a magic ring to enter the land of Mojuste
  and help a certain citizen solve a riddle or word puzzle given by
  Thorzuul. He then travels to Mojuste via the "Bike-o-Tron" (a magical
stationary exercise bike in his garage), while chanting:
“ Thunder and Lightning, Trumpets and Drums, Readers Rejoice, A
  Storylord Comes!  ”

I remember watching this in elementary school as a 'learning' program.
